# Please help me identify this plant. Is the fruit edible?

Tags: species-identification, botany

When free, could the experts here please help me identify this plant.

**Location:** Puget Sound, Washington State, US

**Height:** 3-4 feet

**Date:** July

Is the orange colored fruit edible?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a huckleberry or [related vaccinium](https://biology.burke.washington.edu/herbarium/imagecollection/browse.php?Genus=Vaccinium&Classification=Vascular%20Plants&BrowseBy=Genus&OrderBy=SciName&Display=Descriptions&BeginsWith=V), [*Vaccinium parvifolium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccinium_parvifolium) probably.

It looks unripe to me. I'd wait till August or September.

Some are unpalatable/sour but they are nominally edible.